How to round corners of the mathtools \Aboxed{...} ?, prefer using tcboxmath from tcolorbox package
How to round the corner os /Aboxed (from mathtools package)

If it were possible using tcboxmath from tcolorbox, I would like, but I tried and... no success!
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

First
\begin{align*}
  0.95x&=27.55\\
  \Aboxed{x&=29}
\end{align*}

Second
\begin{align*}
  0.95x&=27.55 &&\\
    \ArrowBetweenLines*[\downarrow\mathrlap{\mbox{Paso final.}}]
  \Aboxed{x&=29} &&
\end{align*}

\newcommand\myboxA[1]{\fcolorbox{blue}{yellow}{#1}}
\MakeAboxedCommand\AboxedR\myboxA

Third
\begin{align*}
  0.95x&=27.55 &&\\
  \AboxedR{x&=29} &&
\end{align*}

\tcbox{Test}
\noindent
\tcboxmath{x^2-4=0}

\newcommand\myboxC[1]{\tcboxmath{#1}} %%% <- This is where I think we shouold define a rounded corners box for use as \Aboxed...
\MakeAboxedCommand\AboxedRR\myboxC

\begin{align*}  
  2.75x+77.4-1.80x &=104.95&&\\
  \ArrowBetweenLines*[\downarrow\mathclap{\mbox{Comment 02.}}]
  0.95x&=27.55 &&\\  
  \AboxedRR{x&=29} &&    %%% <- This is the box I would like with rounded corners.
\end{align*}

\end{document} 


You could use the hf-tikz package (corner radius and colours can be adjusted as needed). This won't interfere with the math:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{icomma}

\begin{document}

First
\begin{align*}
  0.95x&=27.55\\
  \Aboxed{x&=29}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  0.95x&=27.55\\
  \tikzmarkin{a}x&=29\tikzmarkend{a}
\end{align*}


\end{document} 


